Nuxt registerendpoint also mocks child paths
I am just starting to write unit tests inside my nuxt project. now i have the problem that i have an endpoint path available which also has subpaths, like this:
endpoint 1: /animal/dog
endpoint 2: /animal/dog/name
both endpoints are using the http method get.
now when i mock endpoint 1 using registerEndpoint, the handler will also be called when i call endpoint 2. it seems like if i mock endpoint 1 also all child paths are mocked using the same handler.
is there a work around or can i tell the method registerEndpoint that the path has to match exactly?
registerEndpoint('/animal/dog', {
    handler: () => {
        return {
            name: "Bello",
            age: 2,
            breed: "mixed",
        };
    },
    method: 'GET',
});

registerEndpoint('/animal/dog/name', {
    handler: () => {
        return "Bello";
    },
    method: 'GET',
});

expect(await $fetch('/animal/dog')).toStrictEqual({ name: "Bello", age: 2, breed: "mixed" });
// works!
expect(await $fetch('/animal/dog/name')).toStrictEqual("Bello");
// doesn't work since handler of endpoint 1 is called

